# Fligner-Killeen test of homogeneity of variances interpretation

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, variance, nonparametric, heteroscedasticity

I have two samples that I want to verify that variances are equals  in order to apply Wilcoxon rank sum test that assume that the variance are equals.

Here a boxplot
[image]

As you can see the variance look similar.

Using `wilcox.test` I can verify the non normality of these samples:

```
>shapiro.test(table$tempeture_stationA)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  table$tempeture_stationA
W = 0.94385, p-value = 8.624e-06

> shapiro.test(table$tempeture_stationB)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  table$tempeture_stationB
W = 0.95691, p-value = 0.0001091
```

As you can see these samples aren't normal distributed. So I can't use `var.test`, F test to compare two variances, because assume the normality of the samples. For this reason I decided to use Fligner-Killeen test. The result for these two samples is:

```
>fligner.test(table$tempeture_stationA, table$tempeture_stationB)

    Fligner-Killeen test of homogeneity of variances

data:  table$tempeture_stationA and table$tempeture_stationB
Fligner-Killeen:med chi-squared = 82.85, df = 52, p-value = 0.004177

The p-value from the Fligner-Killeen test is  0.004177
```

> **And indicates that variances are different. (Correct me if I'm wrong
>   please).**
>
> In the boxplot you can see that the variances are pretty similar, **what
>   could be the reason for why the test indicates that variances are
>   different?**

This is a similar question [Fligner-Killeen homogeneity of variances test - is it accurate for unequal sample sizes?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/295927/fligner-killeen-homogeneity-of-variances-test-is-it-accurate-for-unequal-sampl), but in my case the sample size is the same for both samples.

Before I test with `var.test`, I know that this test assumes normality, but **I expected less difference in the results of these tests**

```
> var.test(table$tempeture_stationA, table$tempeture_stationB)

    F test to compare two variances

data:  table$tempeture_stationA and table$tempeture_stationB
F = 0.99679, num df = 152, denom df = 152, p-value = 0.9842
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.7244371 1.3715303
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
         0.9967885
```

**Edit 1**

In response comment of @BruceET here the Stripcharts:
[image]

**Edit 2**

The data is measured every hour between 9:00 am and 4:00pm during a month of two sensors of temperature located in the same place, the purpose is analyse if there  are significant difference between the measures of sensors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A boxplot uses only five numbers from the sample: min, Q1, median, Q3, and max. From these you can get range = max - min and IQR = Q3 - Q1, both measures of dispersion, but neither containing perfect info on sample disp. // Wilcoxon rank-sum test requires 2 pop's of similar shape (including disp). // If Flinger and F tests for disp are based on different measures of disp, it is unsurprising that they don't agree as to to equal disp. But I find the discrep in P-values  surprising. // Stripcharts show more than boxplots; would like to see them. // Also, P-val .98 always invites a 2nd look.

Comment: @BruceET I add the Stripcharts to my question, but I don't know how interpret that, I need to research about it.

Comment: I am not familiar with the syntax or rationale of the `flinger.test`, so I will not comment on it. However my (graphical) comment below raises some issues you may want to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Comments:**

(a) When making stripcharts, variations from the default are sometimes useful
for visualizing data. Here are stripcharts for data somewhat similar to yours.

```
a = 24 + 10*rbeta(150, 1.1, 1.1)  # generate fake data
b = 24 + 10*rbeta(150, 1.1, 1.1)

par(mfrow=c(2,1))                 # enable two panels per plot
  stripchart(x ~ gp, pch="|", ylim=c(.5, 2.5))   # narrow plotting symbol
  stripchart(x ~ gp, meth="j", ylim=c(.5, 2.5))  # jittered to mitigate overplotting
par(mfrow=c(1,1))                 # return to single-panel plotting
```

[image]

(b)  I am beginning to wonder whether you have two *independent* samples or
whether you have paired data. The very high P-value from your `var.test` is suspicious. (In my view, very high P-values are *always* worth a second look. "If the P-value is very small, reject the null hypothesis; it it is very large, suspect the model or the computation.") Here is what I got for my fake *independent* data:

```
var.test(a, b)

        F test to compare two variances

data:  a and b
F = 0.95059, num df = 149, denom df = 149, p-value = 0.7575
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.6886359 1.3121767
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
         0.9505851 

var.test(x ~ gp)
  [essentially identical output]
```

Here are fake *paired* data (effect of pairing perhaps somewhat exaggerated):

```
err = rnorm(150, 0, .1);  aa = a + err
cor(a, aa)
[1] 0.9992711
```

You can check for pairing by looking at the correlation and by plotting.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 plot(a, b, pch=20, main="Independent");  plot(a, aa, pch=20, main="Paired")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

For paired data `var.test` shows P-value near 1 [some output abridged], as in your Question.

```
var.test(a, aa)

        F test to compare two variances

data:  a and aa
F = 0.99757, num df = 149, denom df = 149, p-value = 0.9882
...
```

If your data are paired, you should consider the Wilcoxon *signed-rank* test,
instead of the Wilcoxon *rank-sum* test. If you have further questions, please
provide more detail about your data: how collected, purpose of study, and so on.
Then perhaps one of us can offer further comments or advice.

Comment: yes your are right my data is paired, in fact first I ran `wilcox.test` using the parameter `paired = TRUE` and I got
`P-value < 0.00001` and on the contrary with  `paired = False` near to 1, what you mean is that I should use `paired = TRUE`.
On other hand is pretty useful the explanation about var.test, but  remember that is non normal so I can't use var.test 
to verify that variances are equals, what do you recommend me in this case?

Comment: Glad the main issue is settled. There are various tests of homoscedasticity. Mostly for two-sample data or ANOVA designs. Levene's is the one I'm familiar with. Nothing against Flinger-Killeen, just not familiar with it.

Comment: I did a new edit of my data and explained the origin of my data.

Comment: So levene's test don't assume the normality of samples??

Comment: Read 2nd paragraph of this [NIST page](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35a.htm). Also a few paragraphs down about the Brown-Forsythe version. [This page](https://biostats.w.uib.no/test-for-homogeneity-of-variances-levenes-test/) speaks favorably of Flinger-Killeen, but I don't know if it authoritative. (As a plus, F-K has been programmed into R. Still no personal opinion, no personal experience with F-K.)

Comment: I have a somewhat related question, when doing homogeneity tests and you want to check for normality prior, are the normality tests conducted on the raw observations themselves, or residuals? Thanks!